# "all of [album] feels relaxed and organic to where [band] find themselves eight albums into their career."

Tags: prepositions

In [this review of an album](https://www.allmusic.com/album/misadventures-of-doomscroller-mw0003716069), AllMusic concludes with

> "Thankfully, all of Misadventures of Doomscroller feels relaxed and
> organic **to** where Dawes find themselves eight albums into their
> career." *(emphasis mine)*

My problem is I understand both halves of the sentences, except how "to" is supposed to connect them. Is this an established construction?

Answer (score 2):

Jack may be right, I'm not sure, but here's an alternative parsing:

> Misadventures of Doomscroller feels [relaxed] and [organic to [where Dawes find themselves] eight albums into their career].

Being "organic to" something would mean fitting it naturally; the new album feels appropriately mature given how long they've been making music together.

Either way, it's a confusing sentence that should probably have been rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "to where" is intended to mean "such that" or "so that". With that substitution, the meaning is that the second clause "...Dawes find themselves..." is the result of the first.
(There should also be a comma after "organic".)

Comment: So it's a bit of shade in a 4.5 star rating? They hadn't found themselves previously and now, finally, they have?

Comment: I don't see it as shade, but I have to admit the the whole thing seems mysterious to me.